# how can i add a loop to this script to run through multipul job runs

Tags: bash, shell, amazon-web-services

I've written this basic bash script for backing up to our AWS Glacier account, it works for 1 project but rather than having 1 script for each project i would like to do is use this 1 script to batch sever backup runs controlled by multipul configuration files within a directory say "/usr/local/src/glacier/* project1.cfg project2.cfg

these cfg files would contain the aws credntials and also the corrosponding information in the configuration section currently in my script, as this will vary for each project. but im new to bash scripting so am not sure how to do this.

```
#!/bin/bash
PATH=/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin

#### Configuration ####
DATE=$(date "+%d-%m-%y_%H-%M")
GLACIER_CONFIG=/usr/local/src/backup/mt-aws-glacier/glacier.cfg
ROOT=/home/backup/kev-test
VAULT=testboltonvault1
JOURNAL=/home/glacier_journal-test1.log
log_file="/var/log/glacier_test1_$DATE.log"
#######################

case $1 in

sync)
        /usr/local/src/backup/mt-aws-glacier/mtglacier sync --config     $GLACIER_CONFIG --dir $ROOT --vault $VAULT --journal $JOURNAL --concurrency 3 >>$log_file 2>&1

;;

check)
        /usr/local/src/backup/mt-aws-glacier/mtglacier check-local-hash --config=$GLACIER_CONFIG  --dir $ROOT --vault=$VAULT --journal $JOURNAL     >>$log_file 2>&1
;;

retrieve)
# warning, make sure DIR is correct, avoid disaster!
        rm -rf $ROOT/*
        /usr/local/src/backup/mt-aws-glacier/mtglacier check-local-hash --    config=$GLACIER_CONFIG --dir $ROOT --vault=$VAULT --journal=$JOURNAL >>$log_file     2>&1
        /usr/local/src/backup/mt-aws-glacier/mtglacier restore -    config=$GLACIER_CONFIG --dir $ROOT --vault=$VAULT -journal=$JOURNAL --max-    number-of-files=10 >>$log_file 2>&1
;;

purge)
# warning, make sure DIR is correct, avoid disaster!
        /usr/local/src/backup/mt-aws-glacier/mtglacier purge-vault -    config=$GLACIER_CONFIG  --dir $ROOT --vault=$VAULT --journal=$JOURNAL     >>$log_file 2>&1
;;

restore)
        /usr/local/src/backup/mt-aws-glacier/mtglacier restore-completed -    config=$GLACIER_CONFIG --dir $ROOT --vault=$VAULT --journal=$JOURNAL >>$log_file     2>&1
;;

esac
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
for FILENAME in /usr/local/src/glacier/*
do
    source $FILENAME
    <your existing code>
done;
```

The `source` statement will include the config file and the variables will get overwritten for each iteration.

Comment: thats great thanks  i was just trying something simular but i was doing it wrong.  but your methord has worked perfectly

my version was 

CONFIG=/usr/local/src/backup/mt-aws-glacier/cfg/*.cfg

for i in $CONFIG_FILE/*.cfg

do

source $CONFIG

echo "       /usr/local/src/backup/mt-aws-glacier/mtglacier sync --config $GLACIER_CONFIG --dir $ROOT --vault $VAULT --journal $JOURNAL --concurrency 3 >>$log_file 2>&1"

done